# How do I set a channel's name?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm working on Server Stats in my server, now I created some Voice Channels for that and everytime the auto refresh function kicks in it will update the name of those channels via the info of users/roles/bots/channels but there is one irritating problem that the name in the SocketVoiceChannel is get(read only)

```cs
int nMemberCount = guild.users.count;
ulong idUserCound = 623234360010735636;
SocketVoiceChannel MemberCount = guild.VoiceChannels.Where(x => x.Id == idUserCound).FirstOrDefault();
UserCount.Name = $" Member Count: {nMemberCount}"; // error: 'Name' is read only! help!
```

error: 'Name' is read only.

What can I do to set the name of the channel to what I need to set it?
Is there another way?

Comment: AFAIK this functionality is not exposed in Discord.NET. I double checked and couldn't find anything in the docs about it so I think you may be out of luck

Comment: Tip: The predicate you added to your `Where` can be placed in the `FirstOrDefault()` instead and remove the need for the `Where` entirely.... `var MemberCount = guild.VoiceChannels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == idUserCound);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of entities in Discord.Net have a `ModifyAsync()` implementation, which is used to edit the properties of the given entity. The [example here](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.VoiceChannelProperties.html) in the docs, demonstrates modifying the user limit for a `VoiceChannel`. And [here](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.TextChannelProperties.html), multiple properties (including name) are modified on a `TextChannel`

If the voice channel in your code is `UserCount` you would have something like

```cs
await UserCount.ModifyAsync(prop => prop.Name = $" Member Count: {nMemberCount}");
```